# IIS ARR (Application Request Routing) failed to install

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008, arr

I have a Windows Server 2008 machine and I am trying to install ARR and URL Rewrite IIS modules. When I run the ARR installer from the official [website](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing), I get an error saying "The product did not install successfully.". URL Rewrite installs just fine. See below:

[image]

The log files don't have anything useful. Just a line regarding `customAction IISExecuteCA returned actual error code 1603`. This installs fine on my Windows 10 machine.

I have tried the following with no luck:

- Installing ARR1
- Installing ARR2
- Stopping IIS and WAS and WMSVC services and running the installer
- Restarting the machine

Error in the installation log:

```
MSI (s) (E4:F4) [11:48:42:071]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIBB42.tmp, Entrypoint: IISExecuteCA
1: IISCA IISExecuteCA : Begin CA Setup 
1: IISCA IISExecuteCA : CA 'ExecuteInstallModuleCA' completed with return code hr=0x8007000d 
1: IISCA IISExecuteCA : CA 'IISExecuteCA' completed with return code hr=0x8007000d 
1: IISCA IISExecuteCA : End CA Setup 
CustomAction IISExecuteCA returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (s) (E4:08) [11:48:42:274]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (E4:08) [11:48:42:274]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
Action ended 11:48:42: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

Anyone experiencing a similar issue?

Comment: Windows Server 2008 has been end of life for a while, so you shouldn't use it any more.

Comment: I think you can try to download ARR3 from here. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47333 In system requirements, it supports win server 2008.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJV9S.png

Comment: @BruceZhang It doesn't really work. Installation aborts saying that "Installation failed prematurely".

Comment: There's a `View log here`. Please open it to see what the content in log is. And there are some causes of error code 1603. Please check this and follow its resolution. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/ccfda1f5-4601-0cbc-07b2-9ecc93f009be

Comment: @BruceZhang added! As you can see, it fails when running this ExecuteInstallModuleCA module. Not sure if it's an access issue or what. My user has full admin privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install ARR 2.5 and it resolved the issue! This issue appears to be due to the old Win 2008 server and its incompatibility with ARR 3.0. I found the ARR 2.5 link from [here](https://fmforums.com/topic/90414-iis-application-request-routing-error-during-install/)